# C++20 filesystem: recursive_directory_iterator fails with filesystem_error if subdirectory is deleted, despite nothrow function

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, c++20, std-filesystem

I am running a few hundred different unit-tests on **MacOS Intel**, **MacOS Silicion**, **Windows x64** and **Linux(Ubuntu) x64** of a function that makes use of [fs::recursive_directory_iterator(..)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator). In one test I iterate over a directory and its sub-directories while another thread removes one of the subdirectories. I occasionally get this crash, but **only on Linux**:

```cpp
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: No such file or directory
```

I am surprised about [filesystem_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error) since I use the `nothrow` function with a `error_code` object.

```cpp
std::error_code err;
for (auto it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path, err), ..., ++it)
```

I am not able to reproduce this in a debugger, so I can only speculate at this point. I could only imagine that `filesystem_error` is thrown during the `++it` function as the error states "`cannot increment recursive directory iterator`". Is there a way to skip files or directories that were moved or deleted during the iteration?

Comment: Yes, there is a `increment` member function accepting an `error_code` to avoid it throwing, similar to the constructor, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/increment.

Comment: Omg, I complete missed that. thanks! Do you know if the incrementor is still usable afterwards? I dont' want to abort the iteration, it's ok to continue.

Comment: I don't think that is specified and probably is up to the implementation, but I am not sure. There is [this note](https://eel.is/c++draft/filesystems#fs.class.directory.iterator.general-note-4) in the standard referring to the underlying OS API. I think in general the standard does not specify how parallel operation on the file system works, it pretty much makes all potential races UB (https://eel.is/c++draft/filesystems#fs.race.behavior).

Comment: Thanks! I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: Hey. Were you able to continue iterating after increment() raised an error? I am catching the error with increment(err). However the loop finishes in the next iteration I attempt.